# Finding value in a set with custom objects

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I have a class

```
class Node{
    int node;
    int g;
    int f;
    int parent;
}
```

and I've created a set with members of type Node

```
set<Node, MinCost> frontier;
```

where MinCost is the class for Ordering

```
class MinCost
{
    bool operator()(const Node &x, const Node &y)
    {
        return x.f < y.f;
    }
};
```

Now, I know a set must have unique values. In my set, the objects of Node are unique but the variable by which it is ordered (f) may not be.

So, would finding an object work as expected?

Would `frontier.find(Node)`return the correct value?

Comment: So if you try to insert two nodes matching the same conditional value used for ordering, second one will be ignored. So Set only hold the first node.

Comment: A set based on `MinCost` will have unique values of `f` for each object instance. Period.  It isn't just an ordering, it's a strict weak ordering. As far as you're concerned that means if that operator answers `false` for both `(x,y)` and `(y,x)`, then they're equivalent objects, and per the rules of a set, the highlander steps in (There Can Be Only One).

Comment: @Steephen, so what is the best way to store objects if I have to find them efficiently?

Comment: @AtulRamkrishnan I am not clear on your requirement. Do you intend to keep all the Nodes of same ordering within the set, then go for `std::multiset`, you may need to tweak the logic to find as per your need

Comment: @AtulRamkrishnan, you can improve your question by adding code that inserts `Node` objects to the set, queries a `Node` object from the set, and ask questions based on what the code does.

Comment: @Steephen, yup. That's what I want. std::multiset should work. Thanks

Comment: BTW, using identifiers that are only different by case is evil, e.g. `Node` and `node`.  This can lead to spelling and typo defects as well as hinder the reading of the code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Got it. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this will work with `std::set`. You'll probably want to use a `std::multiset` instead and use `equal_range()` to find nodes with the same cost.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare concept, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a).

In other words, when you say the two `Node` objects are not equal, that's completely irrelevant to `std::set`, which only defines equality as defined by the provided comparison. So even insertion into `std::set` won't do what you expect.